# Python3 Counting words on multiple lines?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to count the words in a text file, however my code only counts the words on the first line. How do I count all the words in the text file?

```
def count_word(fname):
    num_words = 0
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            num_words += len(words)
            return num_words
```

Comment: Move the return out of the for loop, so it doesn’t happen after the first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is only reading the first line because it returns after the first iteration in your loop. To fix this simply move the return outside of the loop.

```
def count_word(fname):
    num_words = 0
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            words = line.split()
            num_words += len(words)
        return num_words
```